# Mock Function or variable before shallow Jest

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to write jest to test my component.But as soon as the shallow is called my test fails by calling the fetchUsers function saying cannot read property get of null (which seems to be the initial value of myRequestor).it is not able to initialize the value of myRequestor in the MyReqUtil functional component inside MyComponent.It looks like it is not calling this function or it is not initializing the value.I am stuck in this as I am not able to write the tests everytime it just fails in the very first line where I use shallow.can anyone please help me on this.

MyComponent.jsx

```
let myRequestor = null;

 const MyReqUtil = () => {
 myRequestor = React.useContext(MyRequestorContext);
 return <ApplicationLoadingOverlay isOpen backgroundStyle="clear" />;
};


class MyComponent extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ isLoading: true });
  this.fetchUsers();
}

fetchUsers() {
this.setState({ isLoading: true });
const { request } = myRequestor.get({
  url: '/users',
});

request
  .then(({ data }) => {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data[0], 'error')) {
      this.setState({
        error: 'Failure', errorMsg: data[0].error, isOpen: true, isLoading: false, userItems: [{ name: 'DEFAULT', id: 'Default' }],
      });
      return;
    }

    const users = data.map(user => ({
      name: user.shortName,
      id: user.key,
    }));

    this.setState({
      userItems: users, isLoading: false,
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    this.setState({ error: 'Failure', isOpen: true, isLoading: false });
  });
 }

 render() {

   if (this.state.tenantItems === null) {
      return <MyReqUtil />;
   }
}
```

MyComponent.test.jsx

```
describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
  });

     it('should check `componentDidMount()`', () => {
        const instance = wrapper.instance();
        jest.spyOn(instance, 'fetchUsers');
        instance.componentDidMount();
        expect(instance.fetchUsers).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
     });

   it('Should Render Component Correctly', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(OrionReqUtil, 'fetchUsers');
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    spy.mockReturnValue(['mockItem1', 'mockItem2', 'mockItem3']);

   });
});
```

Comment: It's `MyReqUtil` in one place and `OrionReqUtil` in another. That you have troubles with testing is a symptom. This is actually the case when bad design decision makes the unit harder to test and calls for refactoring.

Comment: I am sorry its actually MyReqUtil.I have edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test does `shallow(<MyComponent />)` twice, in `beforeEach` and `it`, which is likely a mistake. If tests don't fully share the code in `beforeEach`, it should be moved to tests.

This is the case for `disableLifecycleMethods` option, it allows to call `componentDidMount` manually when an instance is prepared:

```
wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />, { disableLifecycleMethods: true });
jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'fetchUsers').mockReturnValue(...);
wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();
```

For prototype methods, another way is to spy or mock them on class prototype before instantiation:

```
jest.spyOn(MyComponent.prototype, 'fetchUsers').mockReturnValue(...);
wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
```

This won't help in this case because `MyComponent` relies on `MyReqUtil` child in order to be correctly rendered and mounted, so it's not suitable for being tested with `shallow`.

This is actually XY problem. Since it's `MyReqUtil` that causes a problem, it needs to be addressed in the first place. First of all, it's a different unit. This means that it needs to be moved to another module, so it could be mocked with `jest.mock`.

Also, `MyReqUtil` establishes unhealthy relationship with `MyComponent`, it's a child that maintains hidden global state (`myRequestor`) for a parent and assumes that it won't need it until parent is mounted. This will stop working as intended if there are multiple contexts - even if this doesn't happen in production, this can be needed in tests.

If the only thing it does is providing dependencies to `MyComponent`, it should be a parent of `MyComponent`, not the opposite:

```
const MyReqUtil = (props) => {
  const myRequestor = React.useContext(MyRequestorContext);
  const loaderElement = <ApplicationLoadingOverlay isOpen backgroundStyle="clear" />;

  return <MyComponent loader={loaderElement} requestor={myRequestor} {...props} />
};
```

This way it can be fully tested as a separate unit. And `MyComponent` can be fully tested because dependencies are available as props and thus can be mocked.

Comment: I get the following error now" Cannot spy the fetchUsers property because it is not a function; undefined given instead if i use shallow.Also I cannot change the main class,is there a way to write the test for the same class??

Comment: Fixed it, it should be `wrapper.instance()`, not `wrapper.instance`. If you're unable to refactor the component, try `mount` or `render`. It wasn't written properly to use `shallow`.

Comment: @k-wasilewski It does if it's used on an instance. Since fetchUsers is proto method, it will work on proto, too. Proto methods are preferable for several reasons, just because they are more efficient and give one more option to spy or mock a method in tests.

Comment: I have not used render before and mount does not work for this test.Could you please help me on how can i write this with render instead of shallow @Estus Flask

Comment: Or cn i just hardcode any mock return value for fetchUsers function so that it does not even call myrequestor.get??

Comment: @OrganikStreet What was the problem with mount? As for render, replace shallow or mount with it. It's closer to natural lifecycle rather than synthetic that Enzyme provides so may work better in exotic cases. Yes, you can mock fetchUsers but you will need to test real implementation any way to get test coverage.

Comment: Actually this is just a support ui so we are not so much concerned about the test coverage ,we just need to have a couple of tests and get it passed.Could you help know on how can i skip this myRquestor.get line and return some mock value so that it does not give this error cannot read property get of null

Comment: Mount is failing saying its not able to get property show in ApplicationLoadingOverLay component ,I tried to mockReturn value using shallow wrapper.instance().fetchUsers.mockReturnValue([]); but still it gives cannot read property get of null

Comment: You need `fetchUsers.mockReturnValue()` before componentDidMount is called. I'm not sure how you did it but it should be like the post shows, updated it. Where does ApplicationLoadingOverLay come from? If anything needs to be mocked, it's it. Mock it with jest.mock and it will probably be fine with mount.